# Import data (description and price) from list of web hyperlinks in column A and return value for each hyperlink in the next two columns

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a file with hyperlinks to different products in column A.

The aim is to import information, product name and price, from the website link which is on the first, second, third ... to the last row.

I modified code I found, but I have difficulty changing it so it continues to the additional rows and saves to the proper places, into adjacent (two) columns.

I would like to add a column with the time and date when the information was imported and make sure that the imported price is a number, not a text.

```vb
Sub GetData()
 
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemEle As Object
    Dim desc As String, pt1 As String, pt2 As String, price As String
    Dim y As Integer
 
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = False
 
    objIE.navigate "https://www.sportystoolshop.com/rotoshovel.html"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: 
    Loop
 
    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("page-title-wrapper product")
        desc = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).textContent
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = desc
    Next
    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("product-info-price")
        price = itemEle.document.getElementsByClassName("price")(0).textContent
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = price
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: scrapping things means throwing them away...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping

Comment: You need to recognize the difference between scrap and scrape, scrapping and scraping. The link to the wiki just picks up the tag you put on the question.

Comment: Solar Mike, thank you for pointing out the grammar. I did replace it with "import". I hope it will be understood clearer now what is my aim.